# how to connect samba AD DC to koha ldap

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos, ubuntu-20.04, samba

I have installed koha 20.11 and samba4 AD and Kerberos .
I have tried to connect by the terminal using the below LDAP search query and its working fine,

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldap://MyIp -x -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=in" -w "pass@123" -b "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=in" sAMAccountName=admin
```

I want to connect samba AD to koha LDAP.

**but I am getting the following error.**

> LDAP search failed to return object : 00002020: Operation unavailable without authentication at /usr/share/test_koha/lib/C4/Auth_with_ldap.pm line 98.

samba configuration :

```
[global]
   dns forwarder = <myIp>
   netbios name = DC1
   realm = <DC my domain>
   server role = active directory domain controller
   workgroup = <DC>
   idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
   server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns, s3fs
   #ldap server require strong auth = no
   ldap server require strong auth = no
[sysvol]
   path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
   read only = No
[netlogon]
   path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/<DC my domain>/scripts
   read only = No
```

koha ldap conf.:

```
<useldapserver>1</useldapserver><!-- see C4::Auth_with_ldap for extra configs you must add if you want to turn this on -->
 <ldapserver id="dc1">
     <hostname>ldap://ldap domain</hostname>
     <base>CN=Domain Computers,CN=Users,DC=koha,DC=kohaconnect,DC=in</base>
        <user>CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=koha,DC=kohaconnect,DC=in</user>
        <pass>pass@123</pass>
     <replicate>1</replicate>
     <update>1</update>
     <auth_by_bind>1</auth_by_bind>
     <update_password>1</update_password>
     <principal_name>CN=%s@koha.kohaconnect.in</principal_name>
     <mapping>
        <userid is="sAMAccountName"></userid>
        <password is=""></password>
     </mapping>
   </ldapserver>
```

**NOTE :** we are not using koha`s default command, i.e. koha-common and service memcached.

Comment: Hello @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT,  thank you for your answer, but we are not using koha`s default command, i.e.  koha-common.

sorry but, my issue is still not resolved.

Comment: May I know which commands you are using for managing your koha instance?? Because, if you are using linux based, then restart the service memcached for koha through the below  command: - sudo service memcached restart

Comment: I have updated my query please check once.
We have installed Samba using this 
[documentation](https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-active-directory-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

•   You are getting this error because you have not restarted the koha-common service and the Memcached service inherent. You can do so by running the below command and checking if the configuration has correctly been done for you: -

‘ $ service koha-common restart && service memcached restart
$ export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/koha/lib/ && export KOHA_CONF=/etc/koha/sites/library/koha-conf.xml && perl /usr/share/koha/opac/cgi-bin/opac/opac-user.pl userid=user1 password=password ‘

Please ensure to adapt the path to the koha-conf.xml, as well as user and password. Also, please note that you can bind to LDAP as user at REALM or NT4DOM\username. So, try doing that.

Find the below link for reference: -

https://openschoolsolutions.org/koha-ldap-setup/